# finding file with unicode characters using Path.glob in python3 on OSX

Tags: python, macos, osx-yosemite

How do I find a filename starting with "dec2file" that has an extension on OSX?

In my case, I have only one .ppt file in the Documents directory. So, the result should be:
dec2file.ppt

Here is the code:

```
my_pathname='Documents'
my_filename='dec2file'
my_glob = "{c}.{ext}".format(c=my_filename, ext='*')
try:
  my_filename = str(list(pathlib.Path(my_pathname).glob(my_glob))[0])
except Exception as ex:
  print("Error - {d}/{f} - {e}".format(d=my_pathname, f=my_glob, e=str(ex)))
  exit(1)
print("Found it - {f}".format(f=my_filename))
```

Current result:

```
ERROR - Documents/dec2file.* - list index out of range
```

How do I get it to find the file and print:

```
Found it - dec2file.ppt
```

Comment: Your code has both a Python 2 and a Python 3 print in there. Don't use Python 2, it's 2020.

Comment: Thanks, Grismar3. I edited the print statement and dropped "(". I updated it now. Should be all Python3 code now :)

Comment: I also think that's your answer down there - the code is not the problem, unless you are running Python 2, in which case your solution is to switch to 3, if you can at all. Working with utf-8 in 2 is a headache start to finish.

Answer (score 1):

After creating a folder called `test`, and a file inside it called `dec2file.txt`, I ran this:

```
import pathlib

my_pathname = 'test'
my_filename = 'dec2file'
my_glob = "{c}.{ext}".format(c=my_filename, ext='*')

try:
    my_filename = str(list(pathlib.Path(my_pathname).glob(my_glob))[0])
except Exception as ex:
    print("Error - {d}/{f} - {e}".format(d=my_pathname, f=my_glob, e=str(ex)))
    exit(1)


print("Found it - {f}".format(f=my_filename))
```

And got:

```
Found it - test\dec2file.txt
```

So, I can only conclude there is no folder called `Documents` inside the working directory where your script runs. Try replacing `my_pathname` with a full path name, or ensure your script runs in the parent directory of `Documents`.

You can do this by either changing the working directory of the script from your IDE or on the command line, or by using `os.chdir` or something similar to change directory before the relevant part of the script.

Comment: I confirmed the working directory is not an issue. In fact, files without symbols are found without a problem. In fact, the small snippet I posted above works fine as well :) The same code doesn't work in the bigger context. Something in my code causes glob to fail.

Comment: Well, then you'll need to share more of your code for us to be able to help. It's likely to be some mistake in string encoding, but it's impossible to say without a look at the code. The specific error you're reporting means the glob appears to not find any matches, it doesn't have encoding or decoding problems, since that would cause it to throw an exception.